# What is VPRT shader?

Tags: c#, 3d, directx, hololens

While using Holographic template adapted for SharpDX, I saw it mentioned VPRT shader for VPRT support devices

`On devices that do support the D3D11_FEATURE_D3D11_OPTIONS3::
VPAndRTArrayIndexFromAnyShaderFeedingRasterizer optional feature
we can avoid using a pass-through geometry shader to set the render
target array index, thus avoiding any overhead that would be 
incurred by setting the geometry shader stage.`

I scratched all over internet but found no util reference to VPRT. Can anyone please tell me What IS IT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VP and RT stand for Viewport and Render-target. Originally, only the geometry shader was authorized to output the semantics `SV_ViewportArrayIndex` and `SV_RenderTargetArrayIndex`, but it forced you to used the very inefficient geometry shader path, while behind the scene, some GPUs could do it with just a pair of Vertex and Pixel Shader.

Comment: This is useful for single-pass instanced stereo rendering, as implemented in this sample application:
https://github.com/microsoft/OpenXR-MixedReality/blob/a46ea22a396a38725043fea91166c6d5b1a49dfc/samples/BasicXrApp/CubeGraphics.cpp#L69